# How can I create a random order list and including same numbers?

Tags: python, list, random

I want to create five random list but have same and not repeat number from 1-100.
I only know I can remove the number from a list which have all number I want and chose randomly put in to new list:

**All_list** is a list I save all the list I want to save random number from 1-100

**number_list** is the list including all number I want but it isn't random

```py
    number_list = list(range(1, 101))

    for i in range(5):
        All_list.append(list)

        for a in range(1,101):
            random_num = random.choice(number_list)
            All_list[i-1].append(random_num)
            number_list.remove(random_num)
```

But in:

```
All_list[i-1].append(random_num)
```

The above gives a `typeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object`. Why does this happen?
Can anyone help me rewrite this code? I will be appreciative about it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
For us to help you we have to be able to reproduce your problem.
Your example is not complete, though, as it does not show what 'All_list' and 'number_list' is.

Comment: Create one random list: `data = random.choices(range(1,101), k=5)` and make copies of it.   `data1 = [n for n in data]`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Does that achieve "not repeat number"?

Comment: `the five random list` should it have all 100 elements in each list or is it 20 in each list?

Comment: @don'ttalk if you use random.sample() instead - yes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is, when calling `All_list.append`, to pass an empty list (`[]`), instead of the class `list`.

The error message is hard to understand without knowing some details about how methods work. Since `All_list` contains the class `list`, the following statement:

```
All_list[i-1].append(random_num)
```

is equivalent to:

```
list.append(random_num)
```

This grabs the `append` function from the `list` class and calls it in a way that treats `random_num` as the object instead of a list. Python sees that `random_num` is not an instance of the class where `append` is defined, so it throws an error.

Of course, you still have another error caused by the inner loop using up all of `number_list`. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forget to create number_list inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Create list of random `number`, and group the random number into `chunk_size` size sublist.

```
import random

data = random.sample(range(1,101), 100)

chunk_size=int(len(data)/5)
_chunks=list(data [i:i+chunk_size]
                   for i in range(0, len(data ), chunk_size))
```

Output

```
[[98, 91, 87, 92, 85, 45, 3, 1, 76, 13, 11, 14, 43, 21, 42, 73, 26, 61, 63, 79], [12, 29, 2, 48, 10, 70, 30, 81, 44, 83, 49, 20, 24, 54, 77, 23, 40, 66, 32, 51], [31, 55, 9, 8, 60, 72, 19, 38, 57, 27, 68, 53, 41, 56, 35, 75, 17, 7, 64, 90], [33, 52, 71, 39, 62, 94, 16, 93, 37, 4, 99, 34, 65, 36, 58, 6, 82, 97, 88, 5], [86, 84, 78, 50, 18, 89, 59, 46, 100, 15, 47, 95, 74, 22, 67, 25, 69, 28, 80, 96]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code on line 3 is where the problem is, All_list.append(list). I guess you meant to append number_list in All_list.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Peggy Lin and Welcome to Stack Overflow.

The error which you mentioned is due to the `append` function being used with an *element of the list* which is an **integer** unless you meant `All_list` to be a nested list.

###### Note:

You Should provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with a clear statement regarding what exactly is the problem with your code and also a clear sample output which you intend to get from the corrected code. [Refer this to better your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Please clarify the following points in your problem statement to get better and useful answers:

1. What type of a list do you require? A nested list containing 5 lists with their  random numbers as their elements OR 5 seperate lists with each having random elements as their elements?
2. > but have same and not repeat number from 1-100

Clarify what you meant by this.

3. > I only know I can remove the number from a list which have all number I want and chose randomly put in to new list

This seems to indicate that either you already have a list OR You want to generate the list then modify it. Clarify the statement.

4. What purpose does `number_list` serve? What elements do you need in it?

Hope these will guide you in improving your question!